# force unicode strings in sql

Tags: sql-server, unicode

Is there a way to force sql connection to always user 'string' as unicode string, without manualy adding N prefix (N'string')? I'm using SQL 2008 and i have unicode datatype (nvarchar, nchar,...)

Comment: Do you mean utf-8 when you say unicode? Or are you just talking about SQL servers weird N'' notation?

Comment: @Cine: you mean that weird SQL [**standard**](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt): search for N'. "Special syntax (N'string') is provided for representing
literals in that character repertoire.
"

Comment: `N'...'` gets seen as a Microsoft-ism because it's not needed in other databases that support UTF-8 `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you *always* have to use N to denote a unicode string literal.

Or assign the c# (for example) string to the nvarchar parameter (rather than any string concatenation)